# How to create a health check for websocket in Google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket, google-compute-engine

I am trying to set up a load balancer in GCP for my application over websoket. When creating a health check to determine which instances are up and working, the only header I can modify for a `HTTP` health check is the host. So I can not add the `Upgrade` header and other websocket related headers (like in [here](https://gist.github.com/htp/fbce19069187ec1cc486b594104f01d0)) needed to establish a connection.

The documents [mentions](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#websocket_support) that websockets are supported by default, but does not mention how health check rule should be defined. What is the best practice for using GCP load balancer with websockets? Is there a way to work around this on my end e.g. by defining an endpoint that automatically upgrades to websocket or any other methods?

Comment: You can review the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks

Comment: Do you have only websocket endpoint in your application? Does it possible to perform the healthcheck on another endpoint?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have http endpoint to but there are routed to two different services by my nginx (a `wsgi` worker for http and a `asgi` for websocket) so checking health of http does not mean websocket is healthy too)

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have loadbalancer -> nginx (on a VM) => 2 different services (on the same VM). Is it correct?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes but I'm not planning to keep this on production so I should not have described it that way, sorry. As my http service does not need load balancing (it's used by admins only) that will be served on another VM outside the instance group linked to load balancer. So it's safe to say I have only wesocket that I want to create health check for: LB -> nginx -> wobsocket service (it's `daphne`)

Answer (score 1):

The Load balancer can accept and forward the websocket traffic to the correct service/backend. However, from my experience, Load balancer can't perform health checks on websocket.

The meaning of health check is a simple HTTP endpoint that answer "Ok, all is running well" or "Arg, I have a problem, if that continue, restart (or replace) me". Doing this in websocket (meaning continuous communication/streaming) is "strange".

If you look at [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#criteria-protocol-http), the success criteria are an answer in 200 (and you can optionally add content validation if you want). When you request a websocket endpoint, the HTTP answer is `101 Switching protocol`, that is not 200, thus not valid at the Load balancer point of view.

Add a standard endpoint on your service that perform the health check inside your app and answer the correct HTTP code.

Comment: Thank you for the description, I know I can check with a dummy endpoint (this is what am I currently doing) my question is if there's a way to work around this short coming in GCP health check (like returning 200 if a n second connection with websocket was established or using TCP health checks instead of HTTP or anything else)

Comment: It's not really a dummy endpoint because it has to share that your application is healthy (enough memory/space, CPU bellow X%, database connexion UP and ready,...). For TCP health check, you can try to use it, but it really depends on the webserver behavior. I you haven't implemented it, it could be hard to have a reliable probe.